# Back button doesn't recall AJAX content location in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am dynamically loading talent content on this page with AJAX: www.icon.pha-group.com it uses pagination to go browse the content. My problem is that in Google Chrome doesnt remember the paginated page you were on. So if I'm on page 2 of content, click an item, then go back, it goes back to page 1. Is there some way I can modify this code to solve the problem? Here is the AJAX function:

```
        function get_posts($params) {

        $container = $('#container-async');
        $content   = $container.find('.content-ajax');
        $status    = $container.find('.status');

        $status.text('Fetching talent...');

        $.ajax({
                    //url: bobz.ajax_url,
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        action: 'do_filter_posts',
                    nonce: bobz.nonce,
                    params: $params
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

                        if (data.status === 200) {
                            $content.html(data.content);
                        }
                        else if (data.status === 201) {
                            $content.html(data.message);    
                        }
                        else {
                            $status.html(data.message);
                        }

                        //all done so call cycle script
                        script_cycle();

                        // window.location.hash = $this.closest('span').find('.current');
                        // console.log(window.location.hash);
                        //angular.bootstrap(document, ['lightbox']);



                 },
                 error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                $status.html(textStatus);

                /*console.log(MLHttpRequest);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);*/
                 },
            complete: function(data, textStatus) {

                msg = textStatus;

                if (textStatus === 'success') {
                    msg = data.responseJSON.found;
                }

                // $status.text('Posts found: ' + msg);
                $status.text('');

                /*console.log(data);
                console.log(textStatus);*/
            }
        });
    }
```

**Code update, heres the pagination:**

```
function vb_ajax_pager( $query = null, $paged = 1 ) {

if (!$query)
    return;

$paginate = paginate_links([
    'base'      => '%_%',
    'type'      => 'array',
    'total'     => $query->max_num_pages,
    'format'    => '#page=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, $paged ),
    'prev_text' => 'Prev',
    'next_text' => 'Next'
]);

if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php foreach ( $paginate as $page ) :?>
            <li><?php echo $page; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;
```

}

Comment: Maybe use variable (with the current page) on your back button, when u click on back button, on loading page, use a script for display the "current page"

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't change URL after clicking on an item.

```
$('.youritemclicked').click(function() {
   location.hash($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Or you can simply wrap your item in a `anchor` tag:

```
<a href="#item2">
<!-- Your item body -->
</a>
```

**IMPORTANT**

Make sure that you don't have set `preventDefault()` by clicking on this item

Then you can go back and forward in your browser because now you have history saved also for this items.

**UPDATE**

```
if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php foreach ( $paginate as $page ) :?>
            <li><a href="#<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: Thank you, the pagination looks like this: <li><a class="page-numbers" href="#page=2">2</a></li>

Comment: Ive updated the question to show the pagination code now too

Comment: Thank you for the update, this renders out as: <li><a href="#"><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></a></li>

Comment: Nope! :( not sure if $page->ID; exists!?

Comment: I think its because of the wordpress function here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Answer (score 0):

You can store/fetch the information that you need in/from javascript local storage variable.
In this way you can remember the paginated page you were on.